# How to filter aggregated elements in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

In official mongo documentation, in [aggregate section](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#within-a-single-collection) there is an example which illustrate `$graphLookup` that include `reportingHierarchy` field in each result element. But how to filter final elements set within certain keys.

```
{ "_id": 1, "name": "Dev", final: false }
{ "_id": 2, "name": "Eliot", "reportsTo" : "Dev", final: false }
{ "_id": 3, "name": "Ron", "reportsTo" : "Eliot", final: false }
{ "_id": 4, "name": "Andrew", "reportsTo" : "Eliot", final: false }
{ "_id": 5, "name": "Asya", "reportsTo" : "Ron", final: true }
{ "_id": 6, "name": "Dan", "reportsTo" : "Andrew", final: true }
```

What do I need to add to this query, to identify that i'm interesting only in records with `final: true` param, but still get all `reportingHierarchy` tree?

```
db.employees.aggregate( [
   ???
   {
      $graphLookup: {
         from: "employees",
         startWith: "$reportsTo",
         connectFromField: "reportsTo",
         connectToField: "name",
         as: "reportingHierarchy"
      }
   }
] )
```

Expected output:

```
{ "_id": 5, "name": "Asya", "reportsTo" : "Ron", final: true,
    "reportingHierarchy": [
        { "_id": 1, "name": "Dev", final: false },
        { "_id": 2, "name": "Eliot", "reportsTo" : "Dev", final: false },
        { "_id": 3, "name": "Ron", "reportsTo" : "Eliot", final: false }
    ]
}
{ "_id": 6, "name": "Dan", "reportsTo" : "Andrew", final: true,
    "reportingHierarchy": [
        { "_id": 1, "name": "Dev", final: false },
        { "_id": 2, "name": "Eliot", "reportsTo" : "Dev", final: false },
        { "_id": 4, "name": "Andrew", "reportsTo" : "Eliot", final: false }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you share your expected output.

Comment: I found one option, of doing that. As long as query is nothing than chain of filters, we could filter `$graphLookup` results, like so:


    `{ $match: { "final": true } }`


Don't know is it right or not, coz we do not isolate initial set.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan, I've just update my question

Comment: this should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$match` to filter out your desired record first.

```
db.employees.aggregate([
   { 
       $match: { final: true } 
   },
   {
      $graphLookup: {
         from: "employees",
         startWith: "$reportsTo",
         connectFromField: "reportsTo",
         connectToField: "name",
         as: "reportingHierarchy"
      }
   }
])
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this,

```
db.employees.aggregate([{
            $match: {
                    "final": true
            }
        }, {
            $graphLookup: {
                from: "employees",
                startWith: "$reportsTo",
                connectFromField: "reportsTo",
                connectToField: "name",
                as: "reportingHierarchy"
            }
        }, {
            $addFields: {
                reportingHierarchy: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$reportingHierarchy",
                        as: "reportingHierarchy_field",
                        cond: {
                            $and: [{
                                    $eq: ["$$reportingHierarchy_field.final", true]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: why would you use `$and` with only one query?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan oh yes you are right,its my mistake.sorry for that.